# Error: in creation of Linked List Display function

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, traversal

I am trying to create a linked list with display() function in it but i continuously getting error in it. a function not able to display element in output.

I have try various online solution of code but not worked on my code.

Below is my code if anyone have any idea. let me tell to solve it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};


int create(int n){
    int d1,d2,i;
    struct node *head, *temp, *newnode;
    head = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("enter the data for node 1");
    scanf("%d",&d1);
    
    head->data = d1;
    head->next = NULL;
    temp = head;
    
    for(i=2; i<=n; i++){
        
        newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("enter a data for %d node",i);
        scanf("%d",&d2);
        
        newnode->data = d2;
        newnode->next = NULL;
        temp->next = newnode;
        temp = temp->next; // newnode can also use instead of temp->next 
    }


 void printList(struct node* node) {
  while (node != NULL) {
  printf(" %d ", node->data);
  node = node->next;
  }
}
}

int main()
{
     struct node* head = NULL;
     
    int n;
   printf("Enter number of node to create");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   
  create(n);
  printList(head);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your braces are wrongly placed, so that  `printList` is not at the top level. You should take care in properly indenting your code. Then you would have noticed this. Secondly, the `head` variable in `create` is a local variable that has nothing to do with the one defined in `main`.

Comment: you are trying to display NULL

Comment: *"I have try various online solution"*: that is not what you should do in such cases. Your first reaction should be to use a debugger and inspect variables as you step through your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Change return type of the create function to return the address of the node like this: `struct node * create(int n)` and change return value to: `return head;`.

Finally, in `main()` save the returned address in head pointer: `head = create(n);`